# SOAPUI: Https timeout but Browser works fine

Tags: soapui

I am trying to call a WSDL service using SOAPUI. If I hit the endpoint in a browser I get a response. However, if I put the same url (which is https) as the endpoint in SOAPUI it just gives me a connection timeout.

I'm not sure if this is a valid test, however, in order to make it more like the browser I also tried sending an empty message, the app still times out.

Is there some HTTPS setting I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have seen this one coming....

My company uses a proxy and SOAPUI does not get the system (I am forced to use XP) proxy settings. So my browser was getting through just fine, but my SOAPUI was missing the proxy.

All good after I configured the proxy in SOAPUI